# Working in debugging mode

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ debugging techniques and I am trying to get a better understanding on adding code just for debugging purposes.

When I use a statement like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
cout << "Output that should only be used in Debugging Mode." << endl;
#endif
```

the cout statement within seems to always run in and out of debugging mode where I just want that line to only execute when I am in debugging mode. That is what I thought the purpose of these type of if statements are for unless I seem to be misunderstanding its actual purpose.

Also, could someone elaborate more on `CONSTRUCTOR_TRACE` and `FUNCTION_TRACE`? What exactly are they used for and how can I use them properly?

Comment: _DEBUG is a compile-time symbol; whether you start the binary in in debugging mode or not has no bearing.  It depends whether or not you are compiling a Debug or Release target.

Comment: @Joe, Before compile-time, even. It's gone by the time you compile.

Comment: Sounds like you are using Visual Studio.  Use the [IsDebuggerPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#ifdef _DEBUG` is a compile-time (well, actually preprocessing-time) construct, and it is not related to whether you are executing your program inside a debugger, but to the fact that the `_DEBUG` macro is defined.

Normally you'll have at least two sets of build options, one for debug (which defines `_DEBUG`, disable several compiler optimizations and generates debug symbols) and one for release (which does not define `_DEBUG`, enable all the relevant compiler optimizations and potentially does not generate debug information, or generates them in a separate file).

When you are developing your program you'll normally use the debug configuration, when building the executable to finally deploy/actually employ in everyday usage you'll use the release configuration, which won't include code included in `#ifdef _DEBUG ... #endif` blocks. Once the executable is generated in one of the configurations it stays that way, the fact that `_DEBUG` was defined at compiled time is "written in stone" in the executable.

That being said, there *are* platform specific ways to detect if a debugger is attached, but normally it's better not to mess with that stuff - altering the program behavior depending on whether there's a debugger attached potentially defeats the very purpose of using a debugger.

---

#### Addendum

> Ok so let me see if I understand fully. So if I hit f5 to run the debug build, whatever is inside this #ifdef _DEBUG gets executed and when I hit ctrl+f5 to run it in release mode, it doesn't run the code inside the #ifdef _DEBUG which it does for me. I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to say. Can you try explaining it a bit simplier if you can. I am not that advanced in c++ and the Visual Studio environment.

It seems to me that there is some misunderstanding about how the build/debug process go in C++. When you hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, what happens is:

1. the compiler is invoked; it compiles the files and generates an executable, according to the build settings of the currently selected configuration;<sup>1</sup>
2. the executable is run;
3. the VS debugger is attached to the newly created process<sup>2</sup>.

When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, the only difference is that the step 3 is skipped; the rest is exactly the same.

Now, when do `_DEBUG` come in play? At step 1, where the executable is generated (actually, quite early in step 1, at the preprocessing stage); whether the debugger is attached or not it makes no difference - the instructions that are put in `#ifdef _DEBUG` blocks are already written (or excluded) from the executable.

The key point here is that <kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and Debug/Release configurations are two orthogonal settings; you can build a "debug" executable and start it without debugging, and build a "release" executable and start it with debugging (actually, this is often done to debug problems that arise only in the optimized build). The fact that a debugger is attached to a program shouldn't alter its behavior at all<sup>3</sup>.

Again, starting with/without a debugger is related to whether you want to have a debugger attached in this run, building in Debug/Release configurations is related to how the executable is actually built (with Debug configuration being a collection of more "debug-friendly" settings - `_DEBUG` defined to enable debugging code, `assert`s enabled, optimizations disabled, debugging symbols enabled, ...).

---

*Notes*

1. this step is skipped or shortened if there's some reusable output from previous builds - e.g., if the sources haven't changed the executable from the last build with the current configuration is kept;
2. actually, the process is created with the debugger attached; this *can* cause subtle issues, but it's not relevant here;
3. actually there are cases where a debugger does alter its behavior, since a process can check for a debugger using `IsDebuggerPresent`, but normally you don't want to do that for the reasons stated above.

Comment: Ok so let me see if I understand fully. So if I hit f5 to run the debug build, whatever is inside this #ifdef _DEBUG gets executed and when I hit ctrl+f5 to run it in release mode, it doesn't run the code inside the #ifdef _DEBUG which it does for me. I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to say. Can you try explaining it a bit simplier if you can. I am not that advanced in c++ and the Visual Studio environment.

Comment: @Morelka: updated answer, I hope I have clarified the matter.

Comment: This makes much more sense now! I wish my C++ class has gone over these phases with us because it defiantly seems important to know. Thank you so much for your help and clarifying everything!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "debugging mode" means what you think it does. `_DEBUG` will typically be defined when you're compiling a debug version. After you've compiled, there's no way to go in and out of "debugging mode". You can compile in release afterwards and overwrite the executable, but then that binary will be a release version and then you wouldn't be able to go in "debugging mode".

It has nothing to do with whether you're attached to the app with a debugger or not, or if your mindset is "debugging" or "just run". After you've compiled, you can assume that `_DEBUG` is forever defined (if you compiled in debug mode) or not (otherwise) - until re-compilation that is.

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check and make sure the preprocessor _DEBUG is not defined in your release project configuration.

If you are using Visual studio , You can check this in Project Properties --> select Configuration as Release , Then under C++ --> Verify the Preprocessor --> Preprocessor Definitions.

#if _DEBUG

The above #if will check whether _DEBUG is defined or not. If defined then it will execute next stetement, if not defined, it will skip the next stement.